# Javascript arranging in ascending order not working

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying sorting numbers in ascending order using javascript and i am stuck. 
HTML:

```
<h2>JavaScript Array Sort</h2>

<p>Click the button to sort the array in ascending order.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">I will arrange</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var points = [7, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;    

function myFunction() {
    points.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;
}
```

js fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/djmayank/uef3xexk/ 
I am not getting my mistake. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Add the script in the `<head>` of the page: https://jsfiddle.net/xqn9oc56/

Comment: You have to set up JS Fiddle Load Type : No wrap-in <body>

Comment: you need to define the function in global scope

Comment: Look at the code snippet, your code works fine.

Comment: @Mouser How does a working snippet help to demonstrate the problem? O.o

Comment: YOUR FIDDLE IS SET UP WRONG. Has nothing to do with the code. Your code is set up to have your code run onload, so the function is wrapped in window.onload so it is not global. Click the gear icon and set it up to run at the end of the body or in the head.

Comment: @Andreas, since a fiddle is to practice. I thought adding a snippet here, will show that there is nothing wrong with the javascript code.

Comment: @Mouser You should answer with your fiddle, not edit OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function using an event handler unless using `No wrap - in <body>` option in JSFiddle.

JS

```
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit')
var output = document.getElementById('demo')

var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

output.innerHTML = points;

function sortArray() {
  points.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });

  output.innerHTML = points;
}

submit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  sortArray()
})
```

HTML

```
<h2>JavaScript Array Sort</h2>

<p>Click the button to sort the array in ascending order.</p>

<button id="submit">I will arrange</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uef3xexk/3/**

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing this in jsfiddle? If so, in the javascript settings, change when the code is loaded to "in the body".

Otherwise, you want

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;
```

to be run when the document body is rendered because you need #demo to be in the dom to add the list to it.

```
// example onload on body
<body onload="initalDemoInnerHtml()">

// js code
function initalDemoInnerHtml() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;
 }
```

myFunction() should be defined in the same script tag as the code above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var points = [7, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2];
  function initalDemoInnerHtml() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points;
  }
  function myFunction() { 
   points.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = points; 
  }
</script>
```

This script should be added to be to the head tag.